# Arranging text inside saved txt file

Tags: java, android

I have made an app that takes some values and adds them to a txt file.
It does something like this,they are strings[] :

```
product[1]  quantity[1]  price[1]
product[2]  quantity[2]  price[2]
.....
product[n]  quantity[n]  price[n]
```

The problem is,most of the time product[1] won't have the same lenght as product[2] or the other products and the same goes for quantities and prices.This results in a messy text layout,something like this.

```
ww    2    4
wwww    1    2.5
w    1.2    1.1
```

Is there any way i can make it tidier ? Something like creating a table or columns?
Thanks !

EDIT : To make it a bit clearer,i want to find a way for the stuff in the txt file to be arranged like this,instead of how it is in the above example

```
ww      2      4
wwww    1      2.5
w       1.2    1.1
```

At the moment i'm using this 
     pw.println(prod[n]+"    "+cant[n]+"    "+pret[n]);}
But this is making the text in the txt file be unaligned(example 1)

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. What is the problem with a tab or space delimited file?

Comment: what's the use case for that?!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the data looks like internally, right?  So, when you need to display it, figure out how long the longest entry is and format your output to conform to whatever length that longest entry is.

Comment: It kind of does,i want to take that file and print it

Comment: @SorinGrecu No, it doesn't. The contents of a file and how you present it are completely different things. Attempting to tightly couple the two is a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: If i take that txt file,and go to a printer,to print it on real paper,it's gonna matter how the txt file is formated

Comment: Which you would *never do*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `format` Method of the `String` class like this:
Declare a String with the format

```
String yourFormat = "%-10s %-10s %-10s%n"; //choose optimal ranges. 
//if you exceed them, it will always automatically make one space 
//between the next column
```

write the output with that format:

```
output.write(String.format(yourFormat, firstString, secondString, thirdString));
```

first string are your w's, second and third are the columns with numbers.

for your example:

```
String myFormat = "%-10s %-10s %-10s%n";
for(int i=0;i<prod.length();i++){
   pw.println(String.format(myFormat, prod[n], cant[n], pret[n]));
}
```

more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: And what happens when the data exceeds those constraints?